# Clean it up, your mucus is dripping

Tags: word-usage

[image]

He has a runny nose.

I told him, "**Clean it up, your mucus is dripping.**"

What do we call for it? Snot? Snivel?

How do I say it more natural?

Comment: You said it is a runny nose, which is probably the best way to describe it. Why do you want to say it differently?

Comment: Between the picture and the subject being about snot, this question is destined to make HNQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most usually the condition you are showing is called

> a **runny nose**

which is characterized by a viscous fluid flowing from one's nose, without *solids* which are called *snot* or *boogers*.

It can be described as

> He has a **drippy / dripping** nose.
>   He has a **runny** nose.

With this condition, children might be told

> Your nose is **dripping**. You need to **wipe** it.
>   You need to **wipe** your **runny nose**.

Comment: I disagree with your definition of snot and boogers.  They refer more to viscosity.  Runny  or drippy nose is watery, snot is a little thicker, able to form a strand, and boogers are thicker still.  Boogers are viscous enough for a globule to hang out of your nose without dripping, or for a globule to be extracted with your fingers.  This is mucous science from the school of [Calvin and Hobbes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calvin_and_Hobbes).  But I upvoted anyway.